Is there a name for when a character in manga and anime is both a 爆乳眼鏡っ子 *and* a ドジっ娘萌え?
And if not, is she just called a 爆乳眼鏡ドジっ子萌え? If not a 爆乳眼鏡ドジっ子萌え, what is she called? Is she called anything at all?

Although Japanese is known to have many terms known as "moe traits", it is impossible to encapsulate all of these traits in a single word. However, combining multiple moe traits in a row is the right approach. For example, it's possible to describe a fictional character as ネコ耳メイドDJ, ツンデレ眼鏡ブラコン魔法少女, ツインテピンク髪貧乳お嬢様アンドロイド, and so on.
爆乳眼鏡ドジっ子萌え makes sense and means "busty bespectacled clumsy-girl lover". Just in case, ドジっ子萌え refers to someone who loves clumsy characters, not to the clumsy person (ドジっ子) themselves. If you want to say "busty bespectacled clumsy girl", remove 萌え at the end and just say 爆乳眼鏡ドジっ子.

Where would I encounter this language? This is a cultural blind spot for me.

@BigRigz If you read modern manga, you'll encounter these naturally. While combinations of three or more traits are relatively rare, you'll frequently come across things like ドジっ子メイド and クーデレお姉さん. There are also some that have lexicalized, such as のじゃロリ.
